# Exception at the uncomitted row added in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which some columns are editable. Datagrid automatically adds new row at the bottom. I want to insert the contents of grid  in database on button click.But when i write insert query in for each loop, it throws an exception because of the uncommited row at the botton
**Exception: Object reference not set to instance of object**
Please help me fix this..
The code is here

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SupplierId from  tbl_Supplier where SupplierName ='" + cmbSupplierName.Text + "'", con);
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string sup_id = sdr["SupplierId"].ToString();
                //txt_id.Text = sup_id;
            }
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdPurchase.Rows)
        {
            string material_id = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            int m_id = int.Parse(material_id);
            string Quantity = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            float m_quantity = float.Parse(Quantity);
            string rate = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            float m_rate = float.Parse(rate);
            string total = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            float m_total = float.Parse(total);
            //string bill = txt_billno.Text;
            int supplier_id = int.Parse(sup_id);
            //string date = dtp_Purchase.Text;

            // dt.Rows.Add(supplier_id, bill, m_id, m_quantity, m_rate, m_total, date);
            String query = "insert into tbl_Purchase (SupplierId,MaterialId,BillNo,Quantity,Rate,Total,Date) values(" + supplier_id + "," + m_id + ",'" + txt_billno.Text + "'," + m_quantity + "," + m_rate + "," + m_total + ",'" +  dtp_Purchase.Text + "')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //object id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                //  string purchase_id = id.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted: ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        sdr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without some code to show what you are doing, and how you are doing it, you are asking us an impossible question.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the new Row using the [IsNewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow.aspx) property:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdPurchase.Rows)
{
   if (row.IsNewRow)
   {
       continue;
   }
   ...
```

Comment: How will this work? what does the IsNewRow property do? because i tried with IsNewRow but invain.. :(

Comment: From the linked docs: "Because the row for new records is in the Rows collection, use the IsNewRow property to determine whether a row is the row for new records or is a populated row.

A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins."

Answer (score 0):

It isnt normal, that GridView automaticly add a row. Are you sure this Row isnt avaiable in your datasource? A GridView is just a View of your DataSource, so the Problem will be there. Which DataSource are you using? Further it is more beautiful if you create a class. Each Row is represented by an object and your DataSource is a List. If you want to get all Datas from GridView you can use the List or cast each DataRow in the type from your class.

regards